# Help with SQL Trace

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have setup SQL Profiler as follows -

Template: Tuning

Save to dbo.myTable

Event selection: Duration greater than or equal to 2000 (ms)

This will record TextData, Duration, SPID, DatabaseID, DatabaseName, ObjectType, LoginName for the events RPC:Completed, SP:StmtCompleted & SQL:BatchCompleted.

I exported the script for the SQL Trace and the script below was created. However I need the trace to write to a database table rather than a file. How do I change the script to write to a db table instead?

```
/****************************************************/
/* Created by: SQL Server Profiler 2005             */
/* Date: 21/06/2010  09:32:56         */
/****************************************************/


-- Create a Queue
declare @rc int
declare @TraceID int
declare @maxfilesize bigint
set @maxfilesize = 5 

-- Please replace the text InsertFileNameHere, with an appropriate
-- filename prefixed by a path, e.g., c:\MyFolder\MyTrace. The .trc extension
-- will be appended to the filename automatically. If you are writing from
-- remote server to local drive, please use UNC path and make sure server has
-- write access to your network share

exec @rc = sp_trace_create @TraceID output, 0, N'InsertFileNameHere', @maxfilesize, NULL 
if (@rc != 0) goto error

-- Client side File and Table cannot be scripted

-- Set the events
declare @on bit
set @on = 1
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 3, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 10, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 45, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 45, 3, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 45, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 45, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 45, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 45, 28, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 45, 13, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 1, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 3, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 11, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 35, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 12, @on
exec sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 12, 13, @on


-- Set the Filters
declare @intfilter int
declare @bigintfilter bigint

set @bigintfilter = 2000000
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 13, 0, 4, @bigintfilter

-- Set the trace status to start
exec sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1

-- display trace id for future references
select TraceID=@TraceID
goto finish

error: 
select ErrorCode=@rc

finish: 
go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Profiler does that by using the rowset provider.

Only the flatfile provider is available for server side traces. It is easy to insert from file to table or just read the file as though it was a table with `fn_trace_gettable` though.