# How to debug or Trace TSQL?

Tags: debugging, xdebug, trace

When working with TSQL I often get ambiguous error messages which would be more helpful if they referred to the exact code location or statement causing the error.  For example "Please check your syntax and database connectivity".  Is there a good way to debug or Trace generic error messages like this?

I read about the Trace feature but it looks too complicated for me:
[Help with SQL Trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083115/help-with-sql-trace)

Comment: How about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268384/print-statement-in-t-sql

Comment: Thanks but I tried reading the link and still don't understand how to use Print and Go.